# Moose Drool Beer Bread in a Bottle OVER 10 YRS. OLD

Tags: storage-lifetime

I bought Moose Drool Beer Bread in a bottle which contains flour and yeast while vacationing up north in Sault Ste. Marie, Michigan over 10 yrs. ago.  I never uncapped it and was just wondering if this could still possibly be good.
There is no expiration date on the bottle.  I checked on line but could not find any info on this product.

Comment: What is the alcohol content? Also, how has it been stored?

Comment: it's not a beer, it's a bread kit ( you add real beer) and bake it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the details: what is this moose drool beer bread, how was it stored, etc

Answer (score 5):

> I never uncapped it and was just wondering if this could still possibly be good.

Probably not... dry yeast is made up of living yeast cells that are in a dormant state, and they become active again when they'r rehydrated. Over time, they degrade and once enough of them have died you won't have enough yeast to ferment the dough. Also, flour doesn't last forever -- the shelf life of white flour is usually a year or two. So, even if the kit works in the sense that you can get the dough to rise, the bread probably wouldn't be really *good*.

I wouldn't waste time on a 10-year old bread kit: toss it and find a recipe for bread in a similar style that you can make with fresh ingredients.

**Update:**

It occurs to me that this is a beer bread recipe, and many of those are quick breads that use chemical leaveners (e.g. baking powder or self-rising flour) instead of yeast. That doesn't really change the answer, though... the flour is still going to be way past it's stopped-being-delicious-by date, and like yeast, chemical leavening agents also lose their effectiveness over time.

Comment: Caleb, while I agree with your answer (+1), I think I would have to invest a bottle of beer and a little time to see how it turns out. If it's good, yay! If not, not much lost.

Comment: If the flour was sealed in a bottle that should prevent oxygen from the air oxidizing the flour. So the flour wouldn't age as badly as flour in a kitchen canister, but the old flour probably wouldn't be at its peak either.

Comment: Yeast, in dormant state, can last for an seemingly indefinite period of time, as long as not subject to things that eventually degrade the viability - heat, light, etc.